# Chrome Frame blank page with GWT app

Tags: gwt, google-chrome-frame

If opening a web (urlX) directly on IE8 with Chrome Frame installed all is ok. (i can see context menu as if I were in chrome).

If opening another web (y) which have piece of js code like

```
...
function inici(){
ifitxamd.location.replace(urlX);
}
...


<body class='dtvc_info_fons' onLoad='inici()' >
    <iframe name='ifitxamd' width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="no" scrolling="auto" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe>
</body>
```

This new page is loaded but no GWT application starts. It also hasn't context menu like chrome, so it's like chrome frame it's not loading.

Any Idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome Frame [only runs for top-level content](http://groups.google.com/group/google-chrome-frame/browse_thread/thread/b3bff61939c9e43a/9ffd13853c809b9e). There is no way to load `iframe` content with Chrome Frame unless the parent of the `iframe` is already rendered by Chrome Frame